# How to check if "{" begins in separate line in java file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a set of `.java` files in one directory. Now i want to check if the `{` (left brace) is beginning a new line or not.

For example,

```
class Name{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

The script has to check how many `{` are beginning a new line and how many are not, and give a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -c '^\s*{' <filename>` to get the number of opening braces "{" that are not preceded by anything else on their line. This would however also count lines where some text follows a brace. So you might want to use `grep -c '^\s*{\s*$'`, which counts lines that only contain a brace (sourounded by arbitrary white-space).

Answer (score 0):

> i want to check if the "{" (parenthesis) is beginning from separate
>   line or not.

It's not clear exactly what you mean, but if you are simply wanting to know if the "{" char appears in the first position on a line, then "^" in a grep or egrep matches as "starts with".  So grep ^{ *.java would find those lines.   If that's not what you mean, please change your question text to be specific.

Comment: One could a `\s*` to allow for whitespace before the `{`

Comment: I wasn't sure if he might actually be looking for lines that do not have a { on a line by themselves.  It would be nice if he showed an example of exactly what he wanted to match (and not match).

Comment: It's better to ask for clarification in a comment.

Comment: Will happily delete it if it turns out he's asking something different from my answer.